# Why Postgresql doesn't allow grouping sets in INSERT SELECT queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The issue here is simple as that, Postgresql doesn't allow the following query structure:

```
-- TABLE OF FACTS
CREATE TABLE facts_table (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    description CHARACTER VARYING(50),
    amount NUMERIC(12,2) DEFAULT 0,
    quantity INTEGER,
    detail_1 CHARACTER VARYING(50),
    detail_2 CHARACTER VARYING(50),
    detail_3 CHARACTER VARYING(50),
    time TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP(0)
);
ALTER TABLE facts_table ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);

-- SUMMARIZED TABLE
CREATE TABLE table_cube (
    id INTEGER,
    description CHARACTER VARYING(50),
    amount NUMERIC(12,2) DEFAULT 0,
    quantity INTEGER,
    time TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP(0)
);
ALTER TABLE table_cube ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);

INSERT INTO table_cube(id, description, amount, quantity, time)
    SELECT
        id,
        description,
        SUM(amount) AS amount,
        SUM(quantity) AS quantity,
        time
    FROM facts_table
    GROUP BY CUBE(id, description, time);
----------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: grouping sets are not allowed in INSERT SELECT queries.
```

I think it's pretty obvious that `CUBE` produces `null` results on every field indicated as a grouping set (as it computes every possible combination), therefore I can not insert that row in my `table_cube` table, so , does Postgres just assume, that I'm trying to insert a row in a table with a PK field? Even if the table_cube table doesn't have a PK, this cannot be accomplished.

Thanks.

**Version: PostgreSQL 9.6**

Comment: That's (semi) amusing.  I had no idea Postgres had this limitation.

Comment: Works fine here after removing the primary key on `table_cube` that makes `table_cube.id` `NOT NULL`, and I can’t find anything like “grouping sets are not allowed in INSERT SELECT queries” glancing over the source. Are you actually using Postgres or is this some weird fork/extension?

Comment: just tested the above script with some dummy data on postgres 9.6. Works fine after removing the primary key constraint. If a constraint is required, use a unique index with all the grouping set columns: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_table_cube_id_description_time ON table_cube(id, description, time);` Please update your question with more information on database & version

Comment: Dunno, but I expect you can work around it by wrapping the grouping sets query in a CTE or `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...)`

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Haleema Ali the solution you propose with `UNIQUE INDEX`, actually works. Feel free to post an answer to the question if you like.

Comment: With Postgres 10 you get: `ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint 
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, null)."` http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c7f5fd4b483c152c314680cc9235d9b0

Answer (score 1):

> You have define table_cube(id) as Primary Key. So, If Cube contains null 
>   values, it can't be inserted. I have checked without having id as Primary 
>   Key, It works fine and when define id as primary key I got error:

```
"ERROR:id contains null values"  SQL state: 23502
```

> As suggested by Haleemur Ali,

```
  "If a constraint is required, use a unique index with all the grouping 
  set columns: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_table_cube_id_description_time ON 
  table_cube(id, description, time); Please update your question with more 
  information on database & version."
```

> is a good option. But you have to remove Primary Key On "Id" and assign only Unique Key as suggested above as with having primary key and unique key again get this error:

```
   ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, 1300, 1522, null).
   SQL state: 23502
```

> So, the conclusion is, with unique index there is no need of Primary Key or with cube there is no need of unique index or Primary Key.